# Local Gradient Aggregation for Horovod using Tensorflow 1.X

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow1.15, horovod

I am trying to use Horovod for distributing training GPU on different servers. Following the advice [Here](https://www.determined.ai/blog/optimizing-horovod).

I wanted to implement local gradient aggregation. In the explanation the modification looks easy `optimizer = hvd.DistributedOptimizer(opt, backward_passes_per_step=4)`.
But trying to use it in my example model results in the following error.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found.
[1,4]<stderr>:  (0) Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value aggregation_variables_4/aggregation_counter
[1,4]<stderr>:   [[node aggregation_variables_4/aggregation_counter/read
```

I am using the native TensorFlow 1.15 not keras or latest tensorflow version.

Is there a working example for this? or someone know how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. As indicated in the error message `aggregation_counter` variable is not initialized. I was using `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`. To solve the problem I add `sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())`. Doing this has done the trick. I am not yet sure why the global variable initializer failed to initialize the `aggregation_counter` variable.